# SAS Proc Report changing header style attributes for an across variable

Tags: sas, proc-report

A sample SAS Proc report code is below. I want to change the color of the header background and foreground for one value of the across variable. I used a compute block to change the column background to light gray using the absolute column references *c4* and *c5*. How do I change the header style attributes for *c4* and *c5* to background=gainboro and foreground=black?

```
data test;
length name $ 10 disease $ 10.;
infile datalines dsd;
input name $ disease cases rate;
datalines;
State,Fever,4847,25.16
State,Cold,25632,131.5
State,Flu,103825,535.82
Lincoln,Fever,3920,44.17
Lincoln,Cold,16913,190.18
Lincoln,Flu,62965,735.39
Washington,Fever,827,56.56
Washington,Cold,3609,234.26
Washington,Flu,16610,1078.8
Kings,Fever,1026,37.45
Kings,Cold,4984,181.85
Kings,Flu,18388,694.33
Sussex,Fever,1411,78.38
Sussex,Cold,5515,300.46
Sussex,Flu,13881,813.11
Queens,Fever,616,26.03
Queens,Cold,2496,107.75
Queens,Flu,12518,558.09
;
run;


proc report data=test nowd headline headskip
STYLE(Header)={background=charcoal foreground=white }
style(column)={background=gray foreground=black}
style(report)=[rules=rows bordercolor=white];
columns (name disease,(cases rate));
define name/group order=data 'County' style(column)={background=lighttgray} style(header)=[bordertopcolor=gainsboro background=gainsboro foreground=black];
define disease/across '' order=data  ;
define cases/'Cases' format=comma9. ;
define rate/'Rate' format=comma12.1 ;
compute cases;
    call define('_c4_','style','style={background=lighttgray}');
    call define('_c5_','style','style={background=lighttgray}');
endcomp;
run;
quit;
run;
```

Comment: Unclear to me what you're asking.  You want to change the background of the cell that says `cases` to black on gainboro?

Comment: Disease is an across variable, and there are three levels. I want to change the background of the header cell that says "Cases," but only for the middle level of disease. The other two cells that say "Cases" should keep the style(header)= attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can use formats to do something close to what you're asking, but I'm not sure it's possible to do what you're asking - maybe Cynthia Zender on communities.sas.com might?

```
data test;
length name $ 10 disease $ 10.;
infile datalines dsd;
input name $ disease cases rate;
datalines;
State,Fever,4847,25.16
State,Cold,25632,131.5
State,Flu,103825,535.82
Lincoln,Fever,3920,44.17
Lincoln,Cold,16913,190.18
Lincoln,Flu,62965,735.39
Washington,Fever,827,56.56
Washington,Cold,3609,234.26
Washington,Flu,16610,1078.8
Kings,Fever,1026,37.45
Kings,Cold,4984,181.85
Kings,Flu,18388,694.33
Sussex,Fever,1411,78.38
Sussex,Cold,5515,300.46
Sussex,Flu,13881,813.11
Queens,Fever,616,26.03
Queens,Cold,2496,107.75
Queens,Flu,12518,558.09
;
run;


proc format;
  value $headerbackf
  'Cold' = 'gainsboro'
  other  = 'charcoal';
  value $headerforef
  'Cold' = 'black'
  other  = 'white'
  ;
quit;

proc report data=test nowd headline headskip
STYLE(Header)={background=charcoal foreground=white }
style(column)={background=gray foreground=black}
style(report)=[rules=rows bordercolor=white];
columns (name disease,(cases rate));
define name/group order=data 'County' style(column)={background=lightgray} style(header)=[bordertopcolor=gainsboro background=gainsboro foreground=black];
define disease/across '' order=data style(header)={background=$HEADERBACKF. foreground=$HEADERFOREF.};
define cases/'Cases' format=comma9. style(header)=inherit;
define rate/'Rate' format=comma12.1 ;
compute cases;
    call define('_c4_','style','style={background=lighttgray}');
    call define('_c5_','style','style={background=lighttgray}');
endcomp;
run;
```

That gets that top row formatted, but, doesn't actually get the row you're asking for.  I'm not sure it's possible to.

Comment: Thanks Joe. You are right, this gets close by changing the background of the across value, but not the header of the columns under it. I'll try communities.sas as you suggest.

Comment: @colleenmclaughlin If you get an answer, please post it here (as an answer) as well!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible as @ChrisJ noted that you might be able to do this with CSS styles and nth child selection.  It's also possible you can't, unfortunately, due to how SAS does things with `PROC REPORT` - in particular, in `PROC REPORT` everything gets shoved inside `<tr>`s *including* the header rows, so nth-child and sibling selectors are impossible due to the headers not being children or siblings of each other.

Here's an example of a kludgey version of this, using `sashelp.cars` as an example.

CSS: (save in a .css file on your drive somewhere, say "c:\temp\test.css"):

```
@import 'base.css';

/* Red the second (really third) column header value */
.table thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(3)  {
    color:red
}

/* Yellow background for the mpg headers under Europe */
.table thead tr:nth-child(3) th:nth-child(4),
.table thead tr:nth-child(3) th:nth-child(5)
{
    background-color:yellow
}

/* Green the mpg-city values */
.table thead tr:nth-child(3) th:nth-child(even) {
    color:green
}
```

SAS program: (assumes the above-saved CSS file)

```
ods html file='example.html' cssstyle='c:\temp\test.css'(html);
ods pdf file='example.pdf' cssstyle='c:\temp\test.css'(print);
proc sort data=sashelp.cars out=cars; by origin;
run;
proc report data=cars nowd;
  columns type origin,(mpg_city mpg_highway);
  define origin/across;
  define type/group;
  define mpg_City / analysis mean;
  define mpg_highway / analysis mean;    
run;

ods _all_ close;
```

This is partially based on Kevin Smith's [Unveiling the power of Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) in ODS](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/297-2011.pdf).

Unfortunately, we can't in any way identify a cell that has "MPG(City)" in it except by knowing they'll be even column numbers.  We similarly can't identify a cell under a "Europe" except by knowing what cells those will be.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dummy column `_c` to the end of your `columns` statement, and add a `define` & `compute` to go with it.

Also, ensure your colour names are actually valid, e.g. light**t**gray is invalid and will not work.

```
columns ... _c ;
define _c / computed noprint ;
compute _c ;
  call define('_c4_','style','style={background=lightgray}');
  call define('_c5_','style','style={background=lightgray}');
endcomp ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the spell check on lightgray. This is dummy code, and I replace my hex colors with color names to make it easier to read for my question.

Comment: I added the dummy variable and compute block, but didn't change anything. In my original code, I am actually using "cases" like a dummy variable in the compute block, which also works. What I can't figure out is how to I reference the header style in the compute block? All I've ever seen examples of only affect the table cells ("columns"), not the header stub

Comment: If you're using ODS HTML, view the generated HTML for a CSS style specific to the header in question, then simply amend the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help, Chris. I am using ODS PDF with ODS layout. I do not know how to distinguish the header in question from the other headers for the same variable - the header for cases occurs three times, spread across the columns made by the disease as an across variable. With an across variable, the compute block call define must reference the column (_c4_) but how do you reference the header of that column?

Comment: You can reference an external CSS file with ODS PDF, and providing you always want the same columns in a particular colour, you can use the `n-th child` CSS selector. https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/297-2011.pdf (see Page 14 - 16)

Comment: @ChrisJ Oh, I didn't see this at first.  CSS nth child *might* work for this indeed.